Why does my file upload from Blazor WebApp directly to AWS/MinIO close the connection?
I'm currently trying to create an Aspire based project where, among other things, you can upload files to a MinIO backend. In order to somewhat minimize the shoving around of files, I'm trying to upload user files directly from the Web Client to MinIO.
The flow is as follows:

The Blazor Client gets a presigned MinIO url for upload in order to not expose the credentials for the bucket
The user selects a file and the Blazor Client reads it as a StreamContent.
The HttpClient then PUTs the file as a stream to the MinIO instance

The presigned MinIO url works and I can upload files using Postman just fine. Reading the file also works. It's when it comes to step 3 that things go wrong. I'm always getting an exception like this:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was closed by the remote host..

This is the code in question:
@page "/fileupload"
@using System.Linq
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@inject MinIOClient client
@inject ILogger<FileUpload> Logger

@inject HttpClient httpClient

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>File Upload 2</PageTitle>

<h1>File Upload Example 2</h1>

<p>
    <label>
        Upload 
        <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChange" />
    </label>
</p>

@if (file != null)
{
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    File: @file.Name
                    <br>
                    @if (FileUploadResults(uploadResult, file.Name, Logger, out var result))
                    {
                        <span>
                            Stored File Name: @result.StoredFileName
                        </span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span>
                            There was an error uploading the file (Error: @result.ErrorCode).
                        </span>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private File? file;
    private UploadResult uploadResult = new();
    private bool shouldRender;

    string url = string.Empty;

    protected override bool ShouldRender() => shouldRender;

    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        shouldRender = false;
        long maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

        var selectedFile = e.File;
        if (selectedFile != null)
        {
            try
            {
                file = new() { Name = selectedFile.Name };

                //This gets the presigned MinIO url
                var resp = await client.GetUrl();
                if (resp is null) return;

                using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(selectedFile.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));
                fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(selectedFile.ContentType);

                content.Add(content: fileContent, name: "\"file\"", fileName: selectedFile.Name);
                
                var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(resp, content);

                // Assuming the response contains the upload result
                // Update the uploadResult based on the response
                // For example:
                // uploadResult = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<UploadResult>();

                // Simulate a successful upload result for demonstration
                uploadResult = new UploadResult
                    {
                        FileName = selectedFile.Name,
                        StoredFileName = "stored_" + selectedFile.Name,
                        Uploaded = true
                    };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("{FileName} not uploaded (Err: 6): {Message}", selectedFile.Name, ex.Message);
                uploadResult = new UploadResult
                    {
                        FileName = selectedFile.Name,
                        ErrorCode = 6,
                        Uploaded = false
                    };
            }
        }

        shouldRender = true;
    }

    private static bool FileUploadResults(UploadResult uploadResult, string? fileName, ILogger<FileUpload> logger, out UploadResult result)
    {
        result = uploadResult;

        if (!result.Uploaded)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("{FileName} not uploaded (Err: 5)", fileName);
            result.ErrorCode = 5;
        }

        return result.Uploaded;
    }

    private class File
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    private class UploadResult
    {
        public string? FileName { get; set; }
        public string? StoredFileName { get; set; }
        public bool Uploaded { get; set; }
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    }
}

Already tried several variants but they all yield the same error...

I would try to write the  httpClient.PutAsync(...) in a test project or console application to see if it's working without all the blazor stuff. Instead selectedFile.OpenReadStream() use File.OpenRead(). if it works, problem is in your Blazor code. If it doesn't, problem is not related to Blazor.

Also, In you blazor code, you can try reading the selectedFile stream and save it to temp file and then use the temp file with httpClient(), just to see if you can read the file. Blazor Server used to be quite sensitive on how you read the opened stream.
